# How to set and retrieve css to localstorage

Tags: javascript, css, themes

I am attempting to create a simple theme selector for my webpage using javascript. The script is changing my css files properly, but now I want `this.value` to persist to local storage and change whenever a new one is selected. What is the simplest way to make this work?

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <link id="themeStylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_v5.css">
</head>

<form action="./" method="post">
  <select name="themeSelect" id="themeSelect">
     <option value="style_v5">Default</option>
     <option value="ds">ds</option>
     <option value="yo">yo</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
const themeSelect = document.getElementById("themeSelect");
  const themeStylesheet = document.getElementById("themeStylesheet");

  themeSelect.addEventListener("change", function () {
    themeStylesheet.setAttribute("href", "css/" + this.value + ".css");
  });
```

Comment: Can you please create a https://jsbin.com/?html,output  project OR https://jsfiddle.net/ project - that will be very easy to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something simple like this should suffice! Read more about the Web Storage API [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).

```js
const themeSelect = document.getElementById("themeSelect");
const themeStylesheet = document.getElementById("themeStylesheet");

function setTheme(theme) {
  themeStylesheet.setAttribute("href", "css/" + theme + ".css");
}

// this just needs to run once on pageload...
if (localStorage.theme) {
  setTheme(localStorage.theme);
}

themeSelect.addEventListener("change", function() {
  setTheme(this.value);
  localStorage.theme = this.value;
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link id="themeStylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_v5.css">
</head>

<form action="./" method="post">
  <select name="themeSelect" id="themeSelect">
    <option value="style_v5">Default</option>
    <option value="ds">ds</option>
    <option value="yo">yo</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey, follow up question. How would I keep the dropdown menu item selected when I refreshing the page? I've noticed it changes back to the first option even though a different theme is selected.

Comment: @Xypter `themeSelect.value = localStorage.theme`